# Rendering Firebase data in map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to render data from a firebase get function but it isn't displaying anything. The images console.log displays 2 values but it doesn't get rendered on the page. Does anyone have suggestions why that is.

```
  function cards(){
     store.collection('users').get().then(snapshot => {
      images = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().image)
      console.log(images)
       return images.map((doc) => {
        return (
          <Card style={[styles.card, styles.card1]}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>A</Text>
          </Card>
        )
      })
    })
  }

  return (
    <View>
     <View style={styles.viewport}>
      <CardStack style={styles.content}>
      {cards()}
      </CardStack>
     </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a asynchrounous function and get a return from it by using a then. You will always get an undefined from it because the `then` finished when your function already returned undefined or in this case nothing.

Try it with using a state and handling the async call correctly like here:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [list, setLits] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const snapshot = await store.collection("users").get();
    const images = [];
    snapshot.docs.forEach((s) => {
      images.push(doc.data().image);
    });

    setLits(images);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.viewport}>
        <CardStack style={styles.content}>
          {list.map((i) => {
            return (
              <Card style={[styles.card, styles.card1]}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>A</Text>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </CardStack>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: The cards function isn't getting run

Comment: To help clarify: the functions WITHIN the View need to be SYNCHRONOUS - the useEffect and useState accommodate the Asynchronous firestore calls.